# Why is the updated_at field handled differently than other fields when removing from archive?

Tags: database, magento-enterprise, magento-1, sales-order, ee-1.11

When trying to move an order from archive back to the sales I get the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''2014-01-09 10:24:01') SELECT `enterprise_sales_order_grid_archive`.`entity_id`,' at line 1 [queryString=INSERT INTO `sales_flat_order_grid` (`entity_id`, `status`, `store_id`, `store_name`, `customer_id`, `base_grand_total`, `base_total_paid`, `grand_total`, `total_paid`, `increment_id`, `base_currency_code`, `order_currency_code`, `shipping_name`, `billing_name`, `created_at`,  :_mage_bind_var_1) SELECT `enterprise_sales_order_grid_archive`.`entity_id`, `enterprise_sales_order_grid_archive`.`status`, `enterprise_sales_order_grid_archive`.`store_id`, `enterprise_sales_order_grid_archive`.`store_name`, `enterprise_sales_order_grid_archive`.`customer_id`, `enterprise_sales_order_grid_archive`.`base_grand_total`, `enterprise_sales_order_grid_archive`.`base_total_paid`, `enterprise_sales_order_grid_archive`.`grand_total`, `enterprise_sales_order_grid_archive`.`total_paid`, `enterprise_sales_order_grid_archive`.`increment_id`, `enterprise_sales_order_grid_archive`.`base_currency_code`, `enterprise_sales_order_grid_archive`.`order_currency_code`, `enterprise_sales_order_grid_archive`.`shipping_name`, `enterprise_sales_order_grid_archive`.`billing_name`, `enterprise_sales_order_grid_archive`.`created_at`,  :_mage_bind_var_2 AS `updated_at` FROM `enterprise_sales_order_grid_archive` WHERE (`entity_id` IN('23037')) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `entity_id` = VALUES(`entity_id`), `status` = VALUES(`status`), `store_id` = VALUES(`store_id`), `store_name` = VALUES(`store_name`), `customer_id` = VALUES(`customer_id`), `base_grand_total` = VALUES(`base_grand_total`), `base_total_paid` = VALUES(`base_total_paid`), `grand_total` = VALUES(`grand_total`), `total_paid` = VALUES(`total_paid`), `increment_id` = VALUES(`increment_id`), `base_currency_code` = VALUES(`base_currency_code`), `order_currency_code` = VALUES(`order_currency_code`), `shipping_name` = VALUES(`shipping_name`), `billing_name` = VALUES(`billing_name`), `created_at` = VALUES(`created_at`),  :_mage_bind_var_3 = VALUES( :_mage_bind_var_4), params=2014-01-09 10:24:01, 2014-01-09 10:24:01, 2014-01-09 10:24:01, 2014-01-09 10:24:01]

#0 magento/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 magento/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 magento/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 magento/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `sa...', Array)
#4 magento/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(389): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `sa...', Array)
#5 magento/app/code/core/Enterprise/SalesArchive/Model/Resource/Archive.php(301): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `sa...')
#6 magento/app/code/core/Enterprise/SalesArchive/Model/Archive.php(216): Enterprise_SalesArchive_Model_Resource_Archive->removeFromArchive(Object(Enterprise_SalesArchive_Model_Archive), 'order', 'entity_id', Array)
#7 magento/app/code/core/Enterprise/SalesArchive/controllers/Adminhtml/Sales/ArchiveController.php(199): Enterprise_SalesArchive_Model_Archive->removeOrdersFromArchiveById(Array)
#8 magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(420): Enterprise_SalesArchive_Adminhtml_Sales_ArchiveController->massRemoveAction()
#9 magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('massRemove')
#10 magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#11 magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(347): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#12 magento/app/Mage.php(640): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#13 magento/index.php(80): Mage::run('', 'store')
#14 {main}
```

I found out that this happens because of the following code (marked with >>> and <<< on line 288 to line 292 in app/code/core/Enterprise/SalesArchive/Model/Resource/Archive.php):

```
$updatedAtIndex = array_search('updated_at', $insertFields);
if ($updatedAtIndex !== false) {
    unset($insertFields[$updatedAtIndex]);
    >>> $insertFields['updated_at'] = new Zend_Db_Expr("'".$this->formatDate(true)."'"); <<<
}
```

All other fields are directly referenced and without a value in the insertFields-array, so the correct code would be:

```
//$insertFields['updated_at'] = new Zend_Db_Expr("'".$this->formatDate(true)."'");
$insertFields[] = 'updated_at';
```

Now, is this a bug or can someone please explain me why all other fields are directly referenced and for update_at there is a special case?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was definitely a bug in magento 1.11.0.2
After using the correct code of magento 1.12.0.2 everything worked fine.

Old code:

```
Magento 1.11.0.2
================
    $updatedAtIndex = array_search('updated_at', $insertFields);
    if ($updatedAtIndex !== false) {
        unset($insertFields[$updatedAtIndex]);
        $insertFields['updated_at'] = new Zend_Db_Expr($adapter->quoteInto('?', $this->formatDate(true)));
    }

    $select = $adapter->select()
        ->from($sourceTable, $insertFields);

    if (!empty($conditionField)) {
        $select->where($adapter->quoteIdentifier($conditionField) . ' IN(?)', $conditionValue);
    }

    $adapter->query($select->insertFromSelect($targetTable, $insertFields, true));
```

New code:

```
Magento 1.12.0.2
================
    $selectFields = $insertFields;
    $updatedAtIndex = array_search('updated_at', $selectFields);
    if ($updatedAtIndex !== false) {
        unset($selectFields[$updatedAtIndex]);
        $selectFields['updated_at'] = new Zend_Db_Expr($adapter->quoteInto('?', $this->formatDate(true)));
    }

    $select = $adapter->select()
        ->from($sourceTable, $selectFields);

    if (!empty($conditionField)) {
        $select->where($adapter->quoteIdentifier($conditionField) . ' IN(?)', $conditionValue);
    }

    $adapter->query($select->insertFromSelect($targetTable, $insertFields, true));
```

As seen the variable was copied and it was worked with the copy except for the insertFromSelect.

Answer (score 0):

The `updated_at` field keeps the last time of any modification done to a record.
You are calling `removeFromArchive` that basically does some modification to the order (removing it from the archive). This action needs to modify the `updated_at` field or the field loses its purpose.
So `updated_at` gets the value of the current time.

Comment: Yeah it does that if I use the corrected code. If I use the given code from Magento I got the error because the date is not a field (you can see that in the resulting sql before the SELECT => , "`created_at`,  :_mage_bind_var_1)")